# $_SESSION variables are overwritten

Tags: php, session, overwrite

My users need to fill a LOGIN FORM. Then, I‘m trying to insert those variables in a `$_SESSION` array.

However, these variables are overwritten everytime the users compile a new login form.

I would like the old variables not to be overwritten. Instead, I would like to add the new variables (from the users' input) into the `$_SESSION` (with same keys).

I have tried to check the past questions in this website, unfortunately I am a newbie and I could not understand much.

```html
 <h1> Login Form </h1>
  <form action="" method="post"> Name
    <input name="username"  value=""/>

    <form action="" method="post">City
    <input name="City"  value=""/>

    <form action="" method="post"> Company
    <input name="Company"  value=""/>

    <input type="submit" name="my_form_submit_button" 
           value="Login" />
```

```php
 session_start();
  $value = $_POST['username'];
  $city = $_POST["City"];
  $company = $_POST["Company"];

  $_SESSION['sessionArray']['name'] = $value;
  $_SESSION['sessionArray']['city'] = $city;
  $_SESSION['sessionArray']['company'] = $company;
```

My values are always overwritten by the new users input values.

Comment: @insertusernamehere hello, i edited now, sorry for that. I would like to add the new variables into the same $_SESSION, with same keys, without overwriting old variables.

Comment: You basically want to store a new set of form values, each time a user submits the form?

Comment: You could add a new array of values to the existing array in your session, like `$_SESSION['arr'][] = ['name' => $name, …];`.

Comment: "My values are always overwritten by the new users input values"
You may have misconstrued it. Each user has his own session. User can not rewrite someone else's session

Comment: @insertusernamehere exactly, thats what i want to do.. thanks i ll get a try ! =)

Comment: @MikeFoxtech hello mike, thanks for the answer. When i try to print_r($_SESSION), the values seems to be overwritten by the new value.. it s my first experience with php, so i might be confused

Comment: So do the same user fill in the form more than once?